# Prove that the subsets $[-2, 2] \times [-2, 2]$ and $[-3, 3] \times [-1, 1]$ of $\mathbf{R}^2$ are homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In order to prove homeomorphism, I would have to define a function in $\mathbf{R}^2$ which is a continuous invertible bijection whose inverse is also continuous.

Plotting the cartesian product on Desmos looks as follows:

[image]

Is there an intuitive way to think about this? Also how should I go about finding such a function? I'm very new to topology and metric spaces so apologies for the vague question. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Use linear transformations on the coordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an intuitive way to think about this. In $[-2,2]\times[-2,2]$, you want to expand the first interval by a factor $\frac32$ in order to get $[-3,3]$ and you want to expand the second interval by a factor $\frac12$ in order to get $[-1,1]$. So, consider the map$$\begin{array}{ccc}[-2,2]\times[-2,2]&\longrightarrow&[-3,3]\times[-1,1]\\(x,y)&\mapsto&\left(\frac32x,\frac12y\right).\end{array}$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Aha! I see the idea of expanding this is essentially just a linear map right? However, how come is it by a factor of $\frac{3}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$? It seems that I could just add $1$ to $[-2,2]\times[-2,2]$ in order to get $[-3,3]\times[-3,3]$?

Comment: Ah, sorry. It's $[-3,3]\times[-1,1]$

Comment: How can you add a number to a product of two intervals?

Comment: Sorry, I'm talking nonsense. Of course, if I want to extend this kind of cartesian product I would need to extend it by some $\textit{factor}$, not a number?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Find two homeomorphisms
$$\begin{cases}
F : [-2,2] \to [-3,3]\\
G : [-2,2] \to [-1,1]
\end{cases}$$
Then consider
$$H :(x,y) \mapsto (F(x),G(y)).$$

Comment: Letting $f(x) = \frac{3}{2}x$ and $g(x) = \frac{1}{2}x$, if I show that each of these are contiunous so $|f(x) - f(y)|  = | \frac{3x-3y}{2}| \leqslant |3x-3y| < \varepsilon$, when $\varepsilon = 3\delta$ and similar reasoning for $|g(x) - g(y)|$. Doesn't this imply that the function $H$ would also be continuous since the component functions are?